# File bitrates unknown/missing after applying ffmpeg operations

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

Recently, I have been doing some ffmpeg operations on some video files whether it's to extract out audio or convert its codec. The output files' bitrate is always go unknow due to some reason. I'm not sure why this is happening. This is an audio file extracted from a mkv video file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to say anything without more information. You should try other tools like VLC to have a look. If the file plays, it has a bitrate, so then the question is why does your tool not display it. It could be that the file is badly formatted too ("corrupted"), so while it tries (and succeeds?) playing it, it may not display a bitrate.

Comment: It is a known FFmpeg bug from what I have learned that it removes the metadata information from the mkv files while applying any operation on it.